# Не выполняется php из консоли Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, cmd

Запускаю из консоли php файл на выполнение, но никакого результата нет.
Ошибку не выдаёт никакую, но и код не выполняется.

```
test.php
<?php
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/file.log', time()."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Если запущу из браузера - то рядом создаётся файл **file.log**

Если запускаю из консоли - то никакого результата нет, и ошибок тоже нет

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/site.ru/test.php
```

**Права** на файл и на директорию 0777

Если указать неверное название php файла - **получу ошибку**, что файла нет

Где я допустил ошибку? Спасибо

Comment: Что показывает `var_dump($_SERVER)` и `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov пардон, всё работает, просто в корне создаётся файл в / а не в /var/ww/... . я и не указал.

Answer (score 0):

Пардон ребята, всё работает, просто файл создаётся в корне сервера, а не в корне сайта.